# The inverse function of $f(x) = |x - 1|$

Tags: functions, inverse-function

The inverse function of $f(x) = |x - 1|$ would be  $y = x + 1$  by isolating the $y$ right?

Comment: *Hint:* Why should an inverse even exist for this function? (assuming the domain you are considering is $\mathbb{R}$)

Comment: Only , if we restrict $x$ to either $x\ge 1$ or $x\le 1$, we have an inverse.

Answer (score 1):

A function can only have an inverse if it is injective. This means that in order for $f(x)=|x-1|$ to have an inverse, you must restrict its domain to a set $[a,b]$, where either $a\ge 1$ or $b \leq 1$. If for instance you take the set $[1, +\infty[$, $f(x)= x - 1$ and you can obtain the expression of the inverse solving $y = x -1$ with respect to $x$.

Comment: Injective means one-to-one

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "isolate the $y$", as you claim.

One way of seeing your error is to first view $f(x)$ as $\sqrt{(x-1)^2}$. So starting with $x=|y-1|$ and solving for $y$:
\begin{align*}
x&=|y-1|\\
x&=\sqrt{(y-1)^2}\\
x^2&=(y-1)^2
\end{align*}
...and we know that we cannot simply "cancel" the exponents. For example, if $x=1$ and $y=0$ then $x^2=(y-1)^2$ but $x\neq y-1$. So there is no way to "isolate the $y$" here. (The problem is that the function $f(x)$ is non-injective, and indeed neither is the quadratic function $g(x):=x^2$ which is why we could not cancel the exponents above.)